# Type cast not working using map function in Java 8

Tags: java, list, lambda, functional-programming

I am comparing two lists.

```
List allUserGroups = UserBC.getAllGroupsForUser(userId, deptID);
List<String> confUserGroups= Arrays.asList(configuredSet);
```

List one returns Object which I need to typecast to GroupData entity. GroupData has multiple fields and want to compare for one of the fields 'id'. So I used map function to typecast as below,

```
isValuePresent = allUserGroups.stream().map(p -> (GroupData) p).anyMatch(p -> confUserGroups.contains(p.getId()));
```

Issue is, for `p.getId()` its again asking for typecast. Compiler asks to add cast again. Can anyone please suggest if I missed anything.

**EDIT1:**
id is of long type otherwise I could have used `((GroupData)p).getId()`

**EDIT2:**
Modified the code as answered by Joop, but getting same error

[image]

Comment: Can you give us an error message?

Comment: You should be able to skip the `map` part. Simply do the cast on `((GroupData)p).getId()`

Comment: @jensgram I have edited my question. The problem here is 'id' is of long type and i again need to convert it to String for caomparing. Thats why I was typecasting

Comment: @VikasYadav you are missing one additional cast `.map(GroupData::getId).anyMatch(configuredVipUsetGroups::contains)`

Comment: @AntonBalaniuc I have tried that also,

`isValuePresent = allUserGroups.stream()
    .map(GroupData.class::cast)
    .map(GroupData::getId)
    .anyMatch(confUserGroups::contains);`

But here getting,'The type GroupData does not define getId(Object) that is applicable here' as getId is not having any argument.

Comment: `List` without a type argument is a raw type. Don't use raw types, unless you absolutely have to (because you are dealing with a very old API that doesn't use generics). See: [What is a raw type and why shouldn't we use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it)

Comment: @Jesper You are correct but This one is already implemented in our application. So I don't have an option to use generic list. So need to do type cast it.

Comment: The type of `p` is `Object`, so each time you need to call a method on it from another type, you need to cast it first.

Comment: @Jesper Please check my answer. I know if I explicitly typecast, it will work. Issue is its not working using map method to typecast

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might try to use something like this:

```
allUserGroups.stream()
    .map(GroupData.class::cast)
    .map(GroupData::getID)
    .anyMatch(confUserGroups.contains)
```

for example with `String` class:

```
List<Object> list = Arrays.asList("a","ab","abc");
list.stream()
        .map(String.class::cast) // cast to String
        .map(String::getBytes) // call getBytes on every element
        .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 1):

Both p's are different variables.

```
isValuePresent = allUserGroups.stream()
    .map(GroupData.class::cast)
    .anyMatch(p -> confUserGroups.contains(p.getId()));

isValuePresent = allUserGroups.stream()
    .map(GroupData.class::cast)
    .map(GroupData::getId)
    .anyMatch(confUserGroups::contains);
```

Comment: First part of your answer is throwing same error i. e add cast to p.
For second part, getting 'The type GroupData does not define getId(Object) that is applicable here'. getId is not having any argument.

Answer (score 1):

If you already know the type of the values on the list, you could cast the list and then use the stream.

```
List<GroupData> allUserGroups = (List<GroupData>)UserBC.getAllGroupsForUser(userId, deptID);
confUserGroups= Arrays.asList(configuredSet);

isValuePresent = allUserGroups.stream().anyMatch(p -> confUserGroups.contains(p.getId()));
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding String.valueOf and directly typecasting id solved my issue.

```
isValuePresent = allUserGroups.stream().anyMatch(p -> configuredVipUserGroups.contains(String.valueOf(((GroupData) p).getId())));
```

But I still wonder why `.map(p -> (GroupData) p)` was **not able to typecast.**

Answer (score 0):

Use casting in contains function no need to cast before it.

```
isValuePresent = allUserGroups.stream()
                            .map(p -> p)
                            .anyMatch(p -> confUserGroups.contains( (GroupData)p.getId()));
```

Comment: check edit1, id is of long type otherwise I could have used ((GroupData)p).getId()