# Error while Calling parent class method using Lambda

Tags: java, lambda, casting, functional-programming, java-8

This is extension to my [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45235965/type-cast-not-working-using-map-function-in-java-8/45236379#comment77439405_45236572)

I want to fetch id from a List below,

```
List allUserGroups = UserBC.getAllGroupsForUser(userId, deptID);
```

This List has Objects which I need to typecast to GroupData entity. GroupData extends PartyData which has getId() method defined in it. So I tried using labda as ,

```
allUserGroups.stream()
.map(GroupData.class::cast)
.map(GroupData::getId)
```

Issue here is, compiler shows The type GroupData does not define getId(Object) that is applicable here.

> The type GroupData does not define getId(Object) that is applicable here

It works fine with normal for loop,

```
for(Object userGroup: allUserGroups){
    long usergrp = ((GroupData) userGroup ).getId();
}
```

Can anyone suggest how to achieve this using Labmda

Comment: Why are you using raw List as the type of `allUserGroups`?

Comment: This one is already implemented in our application. So I don't have an option to use generic list.

Comment: The names in the error message do not match the code you posted. Why does the error message mention `LOBEntityDetails` and `getCategoryId` while in your code there is no such class and method?

Comment: @Jesper My bad ..edited the question. I was getting it for some other method also.

Comment: Is `GroupData.getId()` a `static` method?

Comment: No, its just a getter

Comment: This error happens because of the use of raw types. Cast your list to a generic type: `List<GroupData> allUserGroups = (List<GroupData>) UserBC.getAllGroupsForUser(userId, deptID);` then you also don't need the first `map` anymore.

Comment: This seems better solution. Accepted. Thank you.

Comment: The unsafe cast shouldn't be necessary. What's the return type of `UserBC.getAllGroupsForUser()`?

Comment: @shmosel return type is List `public static List getAllGroupsForUser(long userId, long departmentId) throws PlatformException
 {\\ code}`

Comment: Then the cast isn't necessary altogether; you can assign the result as is. If you want to avoid the compiler warnings, you can assign the result to a `List<?>` and your original code should work. This is all assuming you can't modify the method signature, which shouldn't be using a raw type in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used typecast while fetching the list as commented by Jespher and it solved my issue,

```
List<GroupData> allUserGroups = (List<GroupData>) UserBC.getAllGroupsForUser(userId, deptID);
allUserGroups.stream().map(GroupData::getId)
```